# IntelliJ NoClassDefFoundError for jar Dependencies in other Modules

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I had a perfectly running Eclipse project with Maven and project dependencies. Now I want to switch to IntelliJ IDEA - the import of my projects worked nicely (now called module with Maven and module dependencies), all the Maven configuration seemed to work out of the box (can expand libs and see source code).
When I run my module I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream
```

From a dependent module, xstream-1.4.2.jar is correctly in the build path of that module.

What I tried and did not work:

- Importing projects as Eclipse projects, applying Maven nature/framework support afterwards
- Importing projects as Maven projects
- Invalidate caches
- Maven Reimport & Generate Sources and Update Folders

What worked but is not a solution: I can add the xstream-1.4.2.jar to the dependencies of the module I am running, but then it fails with the next missing jar. So it seems as if it does not find the jars referenced in referenced modules.

Often one encounters the NoClassDefFoundError when there are two libs in different versions on the classpath - I double checked, there is only one xstream*.jar file there.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you, Marcel

Comment: Bug report with a sample project to reproduce is welcome at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: What do you mean by "xstream-1.4.2.jar is correctly in the build path of that module" - is it a maven <dependency> in that module's pom.xml?

Comment: What classpath do you assign to your run configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Is xstream-1.4.2.jar located in the correct groupid/artificatid/1.4.2/ folder under .m2 repository?

If you are running on linux, .m2 will be located under /home//.m2
If you are running on Windows, .m2 folder will be located under C:\Users\.m2