# Why when adding module to other module as dependency maven dependencies no reused in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, exception, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm develop 2 module at a time, Let's say `Mod1` and `Mod2` and `Mod2` is a dependency for `Mod1`. And this both are maven based modules.

So I add `Mod2` in dependencies list for `Mod1` as module (which allow to compile it all together and I no need to switch jar's each time when I change something in projects).

And `Mod2` used `Gson` library, but `Mod1` not. So it's included in `Mod2` `pom` file.
But when I running Mod1 tests, it's shows that they are fails, because

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson`

So if I add this lib to `Mod1` pom files, error seems to be fixed, but for me it's looks absolutely unclear why I need to add that and why it not reuse dependencies from `Mod2`.

Could you please explain me how to fix that?

Comment: Can you add the whole stacktrace? It could be because of transitive dependency. It means some library which is Mod1 needs also Gson library.

Comment: Error appear in code from Mod2. In exact place where it should be. I think it's intellij problem. Seems very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827414/intellij-noclassdeffounderror-for-jar-dependencies-in-other-modules

Comment: Can you run the tests from command line to rule out intellij? Like "mvn test"...

Comment: Show us your POM files, please. Right now you're describing what you think your problem is. However, what you've described should work fine, and there are no errors in IntelliJ around this behavior -- I've been working with it and this exact scenario for years, so you must have something in your POM that's different from your description.